# Angular (7) Material Toolbar+Sidenav; Having trouble with height differences in desktop vs mobile (stackblitz sample included)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have setup a page to use `Angular Material`'s `mat-toolbar` and `mat-sidenav` component layouts in an `Angular 7` application. It works fine, for the most part; But I've got this confounding problem with the `mat-toolbar` height where it is different in mobile vs desktop views.

Enclosed is a stackblitz repository that illustrates my problem in full.

## [STACKBLITZ REPOSITORY](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-toolbar-sidenav)

## PROBLEM

The toolbar is supposed to be `64px` tall, and on desktop it is; But on smaller screens it falls to `56px` and I've no real idea why.

#### DESKTOP

[image]

#### MOBILE

[image]

This is important because of the way the container setup is rigged to work. The whole area is wrapped in this class

```
#content-container {
  position : absolute;
  top      : 64px;
  bottom   : 0;
  left     : 0;
  right    : 0;

  .sidenav {
    &.sitemap {
      background : $pickled-bluewood;
    }

&amp;.usernav {
  background : $ebony;
}


  }
}
```

I know I **can** solve this with media queries; To just set a breakpoint for smaller views to adjust the `top`, but this feels so hacky to me. I want to understand what is going on and see if there's a more natural fix for it that I'm overlooking.

I am also aware that I can force the toolbar height, but this ends up looking very awkward on one display or the other.

I'll use media queries if that's really the only elegant solution, but this just feels like something that should be extremely trivial and it's bothering me that I'm not seeing a more obvious solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the predefined css of the theme, the height of the mat-toolbar-single-row is defined in media queries for different screen heights.

Definition for screens with max-width 599px

```
@media (max-width: 599px){
    .mat-toolbar-row, .mat-toolbar-single-row {
        height: 56px;
    }
}
```

Definition for all screens wider than 599px:

```
.mat-toolbar-row, .mat-toolbar-single-row {
    height: 64px;
}
```

With the **absolute** position of the #content-container it's forced to be 64px below the `<body>` or the top of the browser. In this case it's better tho use the default position: static

> An element with position: static; is not positioned in any special way; it is always positioned according to the normal flow of the page

The most trivial solution is to remove the position and set the top element of the #content-container to 0:

```
#content-container {
    top: 0;
    bottom : 0;
    left : 0;
    right : 0;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Removing the `position` attribute works, except when I set the second `mat-sidenav` to have `mode='over'`, it causes wonky behavior when it opens where it suddenly takes the entire screen height up. Is there a way around that?

Comment: As demonstrated here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-toolbar-sidenav-bcjgqb

Try opening the right `mat-sidenav` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: If I remove the `static` positioning from the other container, it gets the second sidenav height right, but it still causes strange screen jumping when it's opened.

Comment: Then i recommend to use the MediaQuery. Media queries, aren't hacky. They are a popular way to create different CSS for responsive layouts.

My suggestion add the position:absolute; and top:64px;
and add the following lines in the app.component.scss at the end:
@media  (max-width: 599px) {
    :host {
       #content-container {
        top      : 56px;
        }
    }
  }

Comment: You're right. This is the only solution. Thank you for all of the help.

Comment: 3y later: This may no longer be true, because now we have `density` parameter when creating theme. `64px` and `56px` are valid for `density: 0`. For example, when you set `density> -2`, its `56px` on desktop and `48px` on mobile.